# Extending array instead of replacing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, local-storage, lodash

I have a function that replaces an array in LocalStorage with a new one. 
It looks like this:

```
$scope.extendData = function () {

    $scope.recordlist = $scope.filteredRecordsToExtend;
    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
};
```

What I'm trying to do is to create another function that instead of replacing recordlist with a new array (filteredRecordsToExtend), it actually adds the objects from the new array to the existing one, appending them.

I tried the following:

```
$scope.extendData = function () {

    $scope.recordlist.push($scope.filteredRecordsToExtend);
    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
};
```

But it creates a new array with the objects inside it, it doesn't append the only the objects.

[image]

Oh, and I've LoDash loaded, so maybe it could be of use?

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either "flat" a nested array with Lodash ([`.flatten()`](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten)) or you can use `.concat()`, instead of `.push()`, to merge 2 or more arrays.

**Lodash:**

```
$scope.recordlist = _.flatten($scope.recordlist.push($scope.filteredRecordsToExtend))
```

**Plain JS:**

```
$scope.recordlist = $scope.recordlist.concat($scope.filteredRecordsToExtend)
```

Comment: LoDash solution returned an empty array for whatever reason, but .concat() worked!

Comment: [`flatten()`](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) should also work though. Try debugging your code (if worth).

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.recordlist.push.apply($scope.recordlist, $scope.filteredRecordsToExtend)
```

use `apply()` to pass several arguments to `push()`
in the form of array